# Simple one to many relationship cakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

So there are to classes that have a relationship one to many. 
Event Type:

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'event_type_initials',
        'dependent' => false,
    )
);
```

Event:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'EventType' => array(
        'className' => 'EventType',
        'foreignKey' => 'event_type_initials'
    )
);
```

Previously the relationship was by the event_type_id, but now it was changed to initals. The problem occurs in the query when trying to access the data. At the end of the following query you can see that the left join is `Event`.`event_type_initials` = `EventType`.`id`, which doesnt make sense.

```
SELECT `Event`.`id`, `Event`.`event_type_initials`, `Event`.`user_id`, `Event`.`details`, `Event`.`start`, `Event`.`hours`, `Event`.`minutes`, `Event`.`all_day`, `Event`.`active`, `Event`.`created`, `Event`.`modified`, `EventType`.`id`, `EventType`.`initials`, `EventType`.`name`, `EventType`.`address`, `EventType`.`email`, `EventType`.`phone`, `EventType`.`person`, `EventType`.`color` FROM `sunshine3`.`events` AS `Event` LEFT JOIN `sunshine3`.`event_types` AS `EventType` ON (**`Event`.`event_type_initials` = `EventType`.`id`**) WHERE `Event`.`id` = 30
```

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: why doesnt that make sense if you specified the field this way using `foreignKey`...? You should note what you expected here.

Comment: well, I expected the condition for the join to be: Event.event_type_initials = EventType.initials (not EventType.id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you specify a foreignKey it will always match to the id of the related table.
You need to use conditions here, though:

```
// this is important for the correct left joins
var $belongsTo = array(
    'EventType' => array(
        'className' => 'EventType',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => array('Event.event_type_initials = EventType.initials')
    )
);

// for has many this is usually not necessary/possible (1:n), you can try though
var $hasMany = array(
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => false,
        'conditions' => 'Event.event_type_initials = EventType.initials'
    )
);
```

Comment: Tried this but with no luck, the join still stays the same: `LEFT JOIN `sunshine3`.`event_types` AS `EventType` ON (`Event`.`event_type_initials` = `EventType`.`id`)`

Comment: i am not sure if conditions needs to be a string or an array. you can try both. also note that you need to do this mainly for the belongsTo relation setup!